# Change the Year in Date column without changing the month and day using Python

Tags: python

I have to fix the year in column 'Date Posted'. Some of the dates were mistyped as '2019' instead of '2017' (See Current Dataframe below). Is there a way to fix only the year without changing the month and day? This dataframe is a subset of a huge dataframe and I need to automate the fixing of date error. Please help.

Current Dataframe:

```
Name                  Date Posted
A                        10-28-2017
A                        10-28-2017
A                        10-26-2017
A                        10-24-2017 
B                        10-02-2019
B                        10-08-2019
B                        10-04-2017
B                        10-05-2019
C                        9-15-2017
C                        9-02-2017 
C                        9-07-2017
C                        9-16-2017
```

Expected Output:

```
Name                  Date Posted
A                        10-28-2017
A                        10-28-2017
A                        10-26-2017
A                        10-24-2017 
B                        10-02-2017
B                        10-08-2017
B                        10-04-2017
B                        10-05-2017
C                        9-15-2017
C                        9-02-2017 
C                        9-07-2017
C                        9-16-2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Date Posted` columns is in `datetime` format, can use the `replace` function. Below should work:

```
df["Date Posted"].map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2017))
```

Comment: your code worked and gave me the correct output, however when I tried to save the change in csv and re-open it, it does not show the date change.

Comment: You will need to assign it back to your column, do `df["Date Posted"] = df["Date Posted"].map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2017))` and then save it.